# How to reduce log level for specific classes/packages in logback.xml

Tags: logback

In our application, the information useful for me to analyze performance issues is reported at DEBUG level.

However, it can be very verbose for some classes, and I'd like to change the log level for those specific classes only to INFO level instead of DEBUG.

I'm able to do the opposite in the logback by setting the global log level to INFO, and setting a specific class/package to DEBUG, but I can't seem to make the opposite work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance